# Converting EGCD Equation to Python

Tags: python

Attempting to convert this EGCD equation into python.

```
egcd(a, b) = (1, 0), if b = 0
= (t, s - q * t), otherwise, where
q = a / b (note: integer division)
r = a mod b
(s, t) = egcd(b, r)
```

The test I used was egcd(5, 37) which should return (15,-2) but is returning (19.5, -5.135135135135135)

My code is:

```
def egcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return (1, 0)
    else:
        q = a / b # Calculate q
        r = a % b # Calculate r
        (s,t) = egcd(b,r) # Calculate (s, t) by calling egcd(b, r)
        return (t,s-q*t) # Return (t, s-q*t)
```

Comment: Change `q = a / b` for `q = a // b`

Answer (score 1):

`a / b` in Python 3 is "true division" the result is non-truncating floating point division even when both operands are `int`s.

To fix, either use `//` instead (which is floor division):

```
q = a // b
```

or [use `divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) to perform both division and remainder as a single computation, replacing both of these lines:

```
q = a / b
r = a % b
```

with just:

```
q, r = divmod(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `q = a / b` for `q = a // b`